How to guarantee component files are installed to the specified disk?
I’m trying create a shared wix library that defines a shared install folder, then in the main wix install file for each project I concatenate the final folder for that specific project.
Shared library:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Fragment>
    <SetDirectory Id="DRIVE_ROOT" Value="C:"/>
  </Fragment>
  
  <Fragment>
    <!-- Define a directory that can be shared between all the windows services -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="DRIVE_ROOT">
        <Directory Id="MYSOLUTION" Name="MySolution">
          <Directory Id="WINDOWS_SERVICES" Name="WindowsServices"/>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>

service installer:
 <Fragment>
   <!-- finalize install location by joining shared windows services folder with the folder for this specific service -->
   <DirectoryRef Id="WINDOWS_SERVICES">
     <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyService" />
   </DirectoryRef>
 </Fragment>

<Fragment>
   <!-- define the files to install -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="MainExecutable" Guid="605ACF3F-A9A1-4627-82BA-27738EFDE0FE">
           <File Id="MyServiceEXE" Name="$(var.MyService.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.MyService.TargetPath)"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>

My problem is that the install always happens on D:\MySolution\WindowsServices\MyService even though I specified C: in the shared library.
Please recommend how I may better control which disk my installer uses.

What does the log file show?

@RobMensching what log file are you referring to? Where would I see it?
